# Why does the NS records keep randomly changing when queried?

Tags: dns

```
dig NS soundshare.co.uk


;; ANSWER SECTION:
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-1179.awsdns-19.org.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-1909.awsdns-46.co.uk.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-311.awsdns-38.com.
soundshare.co.uk.   168415  IN  NS  ns-972.awsdns-57.net.
```

a few seconds later:

```
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-1289.awsdns-33.org.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-1581.awsdns-05.co.uk.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-41.awsdns-05.com.
soundshare.co.uk.   167643  IN  NS  ns-806.awsdns-36.net.
```

Why might this be occuring?

These are all values that I've previously set. Should I get in contact with the domain provider?

Answer (score 3):

This is a form of load distribution. By giving out different and presumably random name servers then the requests to those servers can be fairly balanced.

Comment: This does not explain why the RRset changes!

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I don't mean to sound to dense but that was not asked by the OP. It seems more like you're going on a wild goose chase. DNS names changing between TTL periods is normal. My answer I suppose is slightly misleading for a different reason though. The wording of the question: "randomly changes" that is the different set of NSs (the RRset as you call it) observed is definitely load balancing. It wasn't specified nor did it ever occur to me that "a few seconds later" meant that this happened repeatedly more than once between TTL periods which would signal something ELSE is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Given that I still think my answer applies to what the OP is asking. It explains why the NSs changed "randomly." Although if you have suggestions for how to make it less misleading for the pedantic I'd be more than happy to edit my answer.

Comment: "Why this might be occuring" is not the OP asking for why the RRset is changing for you? Then we disagree. " DNS names changing between TTL periods is normal" does not mean anything. NAmeservers do not change at registry authoritative nameservers except if the owner changes them. The observation has nothing to do with load balancing, you do not seem to understand how DNS works at all, and RRset is not like I call it it is standard term in DNS protocol, if you learn it. No your answers completely misses the point and there is nothing to improve, sorry.

Comment: Your answer is not misleading it is just plain wrong. The OP sees different views of his domain because he is hitting different recursive nameservers (this part is missing in his  question but this is the most simple and natural explanations) that cached different sets of NS because the OP just changed the content of his zone and it has a 48 hours TTL. I bet that past this delay he will not see any differences any more between all his queries, showing that it has nothing to do with "load balancing". Try yourself, do queries, do you get different replies each time? I am sure no, or show proofs.

Comment: "Try yourself, do queries, do you get different replies each time?" You're asking me to confirm a standard you set and not the OP. As far as we know the ongoing changes to the NS were happening over days which would be normal.

Comment: I am not setting a standard I am asking you to show proofs of what you say (note the proofs in my answer). You do not want to base your answer on factual data, I understand and will stop arguing with you then since obviously you do not want to stay in the realm of factual things. And you are reading things that are not written in the question, so I will let you in your delusion.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek 

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers to date miss this very important point: your dig results are worthless... because we do not see what nameserver replied to you. Based on the TTL it seems you query recursive nameservers but which?

What you observe has nothing to do with anycast, nor RRset order changes. You seem to observe different NS at each query which is strange, but again, which nameserver replies to you?

Here is what could have happened to you: in your setup you do not hit the same recursive nameserver each time. So you observe what they have in their cache. If you look at whois you see an update has been applied to this domain yesterday. Maybe a DNS change. So one of the nameserver you query has the data just before the change, and the other one just after. I suppose if you do queries now you will get the same replies always, or after 46 hour as the TTLs you report are huge.
If it is your domain you probably have made multiple DNS changes yesterday and hence now caches do not have the same information any more. This is normal, you just need to wait.

Changes in your DNS are indeed clearly visible:
https://securitytrails.com/domain/soundshare.co.uk/history/ns
and [screenshot](https://screenshots.firefox.com/GXylsyziawiJYA8i/securitytrails.com)

Try doing your observations by both consulting known public servers (`1.1.1.1`, `8.8.8.8` and `9.9.9.9` to start with) as well as the authoritative nameservers for `.co.uk`. If you do that you will see that you always get the exact same **set** of nameservers (which means the order can change, this is per the DNS standard, but the set content does not change).

The authoritative nameservers all reply the same thing, as expected:

```
$ (for ns in $(dig NS co.uk +short); do dig soundshare.co.uk @$ns +noall +authority | grep NS; done) | sort | uniq -c
   8 soundshare.co.uk.  172800 IN NS ns1033.ui-dns.org.
   8 soundshare.co.uk.  172800 IN NS ns1039.ui-dns.biz.
   8 soundshare.co.uk.  172800 IN NS ns1079.ui-dns.de.
   8 soundshare.co.uk.  172800 IN NS ns1089.ui-dns.com.
```

Only `1.1.1.1` is not able to resolve it (I do not know why yet), the other too reply the same thing:

```
$ (for ns in 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9; do dig soundshare.co.uk @$ns NS | grep 'IN NS '; done) | awk '{print $5}' | sort | uniq -c
   2 ns1033.ui-dns.org.
   2 ns1039.ui-dns.biz.
   2 ns1079.ui-dns.de.
   2 ns1089.ui-dns.com.
```

Comment: I do agree that the OP is possibly not talking with the same DNS servers directly, but besides the possibility of asking different resolvers, that happens by design nowadays in large worldwide service providers for high availability/load balancing purposes. I would not bet my money on ongoing DNS changes. What it might happens is some resolvers caching a view of answer(s) on a particular time, and serving their partial view of that answers while they have it on cache. Not sure if I am explaining myself clearly.

Comment: No, you are not understanding the issue at all. Query the authoritative nameservers: it will ALWAYS be the same NS RRset, no changes! Anycast has nothing to do at this level. Please stop just trying to repeat the same thing as it does not prove anything. Anycast is when. given name resolves to an IP that is routed differently/in different locations. The NS RRset (names) never changes, but the names could be anycasted. This WOULD NOT be visible doing a DNS query. I am SURE the OP changed its NS multiple times yesterday.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro see my edit, NS have been indeed changed yesterday which proves completely my point. No need to resort to other convoluted solutions that have nothing to do with this case.

Comment: I am still seeing them rotating as of now, the NS change radically, whilst maybe one in common between each dig request. I still think it is by design, and not any DNS update.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro great then show the requests and especially which nameserver replies to you, then we can discuss (but please carefully read my answer first and the difference between authoritative and recursive nameservers replies). Otherwise you are just trying to argue a lost case. This has a lot to do with DNS updates and nothing at all to do with anycast, even if you try to push this idea everytime.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro And **again** rotation inside the RRset is PER DNS DESIGN (and this is different from changes inside the RRset). This has NOTHING TO DO with Anycast. You seem to mix many things on purpose to blur something that is crystal clear.

Comment: I never said it is due to anycast or whatever, just there is a complex infra-structure behind it, and the OP is seeing intended behaviour, and then gave examples of what technologies can be behind a wordwide setup. It was you that fixated in the two examples I gave, not me.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No you have not proved anything. There is no "complex" infra-structure behind it. Just recursive nameservers having different states because the authoritative nameservers have been changed yesterday and the TTLs seem to be around 48h. If you can not understand nor agree on these simple facts, I think I should stop trying to explain to you.

Comment: Calm down please. You are right it was updated...Something is amiss. Either caching as you say, or someone messed up, and the answers are not the same on all servers. Wont have time to check it now.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am calm, just make sure to use Occam's razor in your answers, thank you.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro so that will be my last point with you as you really seem not to want to accept simple facts. Yesterday there was RRset A. Some recursive nameservers caught it and will cache it for 48 hours. Then RRset A was replaced by RRset B. After that change recursive nameservers will now get RRset B and cache it too. So depending on which recursive nameserver you query you will get either RRset A or RRSet B. There is absolutely nothing extraordinary here. Just **BASIC** DNS. Wait 48 hours and see all recursive nameservers having now the same information (if no further updates of course).